# Provisioning profile for every app?

Tags: app-store-connect

I uploaded my first app a couple weeks ago. I followed a tutorial on how to upload an app to the app store. I'm ready to upload my second app, do i need to create a new provisioning profile? I used my name for my first profile so i'm guessing i can use it again, i just want to be sure. I've made lots of errors uploading my first app so i want to make sure it goes well for my second app. 
Please keep in mind i've been coding for 2 months and i'm only 17 so simple answers would be best. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a provisioning profile for each app you want to submit, no matter how you named the provisioning profile.

The provisioning profile is "reusable" in case it is an update of an app. But different bundle ids (i.e. different apps) need different provisioning profiles.